# Create a table on another instance

Tags: sql, instance

I have used Stackoverflow for a while now, but this is my first time posting a question... please be gentle.

I work for a HR software provider and am working on a process to copy data from one database to another.

I have the following script that will generate insert statements based on custom tables that the clients can create within the system:

```
select 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [__TARGETINST__].[__TARGETDB__].[dbo].[SysObjects] o
 INNER JOIN [__TARGETINST__].[__TARGETDB__].[dbo].[SysColumns] 
c ON o.ID = c.ID WHERE o.name =' 
+ '''' + name + '''' + ') ' +'Begin' + ' ' + 'CREATE TABLE' + ' ' + name + ' 
(Employeeid UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL, ' + 'Sequence bigint NOT NULL,RUID 
UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL,' + 
'SYS_EffectiveDate datetime NOT NULL, SYS_ModifiedBy Nvarchar(50) NULL, 
SYS_ModifiedDate datetime NOT NULL,' + 'SYS_RequestID UniqueIdentifier NULL, 
Primary Key (Employeeid, sequence),' +
' Foreign key (employeeid) references employee(employeeid))' + ' end'
from [__SOURCEINST__].[__SOURCEDB__].sys.tables 
where name like '%_client'
and name in (select dbtable from [__SOURCEINST__].[__SOURCEDB__].[dbo] 
IntranetPages)
and name not in ('Employeetable1_CLIENT','Employeetable2_CLIENT')
and type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
```

This will ultimately create a few insert statements that have been designed to create the empty tables in the **TARGETDB**, for example:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT * FROM [__TARGETINST__].[__TARGETDB__].[dbo].[SysObjects] o 
    INNER JOIN [__TARGETINST__].[__TARGETDB__].[dbo].[SysColumns] c 
    ON o.ID = c.ID WHERE o.name ='newtable_CLIENT'
) 
Begin 
CREATE TABLE newtable_CLIENT
(
Employeeid UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL, 
Sequence bigint NOT NULL,
RUID UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL,
SYS_EffectiveDate datetime NOT NULL, 
SYS_ModifiedBy Nvarchar(50) NULL, 
SYS_ModifiedDate datetime NOT NULL,
SYS_RequestID UniqueIdentifier NULL, 
Primary Key (Employeeid, sequence), 
Foreign key (employeeid) references employee(employeeid)
) 
end
```

The issue that I think I have is that there are 3 instances involved. [**TARGETINST**] and [**SOURCEINST**] are not linked (afraid they can't be) but I do have another instance that IS linked to both of them. I am trying to run the script on the 'TRANSFERINST' but am getting the following error:

```
Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Line 52
Foreign key '__KEY__' references invalid table 'employee'.
```

I figured that this was an issue with the Create, in that SQL did not know where to create the table. so I updated to this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT * FROM [__TARGETINST__].[__TARGETDB__].[dbo].[SysObjects] o 
    INNER JOIN [__TARGETINST__].[__TARGETDB__].[dbo].[SysColumns] c 
    ON o.ID = c.ID WHERE o.name ='newtable_CLIENT'
) 
Begin 
CREATE TABLE [__TARGETINST__].[__TARGETDB__].[dbo].newtable_CLIENT
(
Employeeid UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL, 
Sequence bigint NOT NULL,
RUID UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL,
SYS_EffectiveDate datetime NOT NULL, 
SYS_ModifiedBy Nvarchar(50) NULL, 
SYS_ModifiedDate datetime NOT NULL,
SYS_RequestID UniqueIdentifier NULL, 
Primary Key (Employeeid, sequence), 
Foreign key (employeeid) references employee(employeeid)
) 
end
```

but then received the message below:

The object name '[**TARGETINST**].[**TARGETDB**].dbo.newtable' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

I am a little stuck now, and can't seem to find any answers out there in any searches I have done.

I am not even sure if it is possible to create a blank table on another instance. I am able to query and update the different DBs from the 'TRANSFERINST'.

I have seen that it is possible to 'select * into' however I need the tables to be blank so that the next script in the process can then create the relevant custom columns. Once the tables and columns are in place I will be looking to populate them from the data held on the **SOURCEDB**.

Hope this makes sense and looking forward to hearing your thoughts.

Cheers.

Comment: Please, simplify your code and structure.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Management Studio 14.0.17224.0

Comment: Apologies, I am not sure how I can simplify the code any further. The first chunk is the dynamic SQL used to generate the second chunk, and the third chunk is following an amendment to try force the script to run on the correct server.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Just needed to wrap the create table in an execute 'AT'

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT * FROM [__TARGETINST__].[__TARGETDB__].[dbo].[SysObjects] o 
INNER JOIN [__TARGETINST__].[__TARGETDB__].[dbo].[SysColumns] c 
ON o.ID = c.ID WHERE o.name ='newtable_CLIENT'
) 
Begin 

EXECUTE ('

CREATE TABLE [__TARGETDB__].[dbo].newtable_CLIENT
(
Employeeid UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL, 
Sequence bigint NOT NULL,
RUID UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL,
SYS_EffectiveDate datetime NOT NULL, 
SYS_ModifiedBy Nvarchar(50) NULL, 
SYS_ModifiedDate datetime NOT NULL,
SYS_RequestID UniqueIdentifier NULL, 
Primary Key (Employeeid, sequence), 
Foreign key (employeeid) references employee(employeeid)
)

') AT [__TARGETINST__]

end
```

So simple when you know how!